# How to create Lambda using CloudFormation and only deploy zip file after?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have the following CloudFormation template:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
   HostingBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
         BucketName: "my-hosting-bucket"
   LambdaExecutionRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
         AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
               - Effect: Allow
                 Principal:
                  Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
                 Action: sts:AssumeRole
         ManagedPolicyArns:
            - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
   MyFunction:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
      Properties:
         Handler: index.handler
         Runtime: nodejs12.x
         Role: !GetAtt 'LambdaExecutionRole.Arn'
         Timeout: 300
         Code:
            S3Bucket: !Ref 'HostingBucket'
            S3Key: !Sub 'lambda/backend.zip'
```

But while deploying this I get the following error:

> Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: NoSuchKey. S3 Error Message: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: SOME-REQUEST-ID)"

Now I understand why the error occurs: my lambda is trying to get the deployed code, but it's not there yet because the S3 is created in the same stack. Probably I will need the following steps:

1. Create S3 bucket (via CloudFormation)
2. Deploy lambda code to created S3 bucket
3. Create lambda (via CloudFormation)

How can I deploy this CloudFormation template before deploying my Lambda handler to S3? I'd like to use the following flow:

1. Create S3 bucket *and* lambda (via CloudFormation)
2. Deploy lambda code to created S3 bucket
3. Have lambda pick up the newest code (which happens automatically iirc)

Comment: No, Lambda does not automagically pick up new code that you upload to S3. The code in S3 that you point Lambda at when you create (or update) the function is copied from S3 to somewhere within the Lambda service's control at that time.

Comment: Alright so I have to follow the first set of steps: 1. Create bucket, 2. deploy code, 3. Create function?

Comment: Yes, or create bucket, deploy dummy code, create function, deploy real code, update function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the only way to do that is that you split the stacks one for lambda deployment bucket and another one for all lambda resources.

Answer (score 0):

You would typically deploy your artifact into S3 during build time in a pipeline.

Comment: Except you need to provision an S3 bucket first, which means you need to deploy your CF stack first.